# Fallo al pasar archivos desde VPS a un hospedaje compartido por FTP

Tags: php, ftp

La carpeta del *FTP* de destino tiene permisos 775, y el usuario *FTP* es el usuario administrador de esa cuenta de hospedaje compartido y por tanto entiendo que los permisos al hacerse la transferencia son los adecuados para poder escribir.

El código incluye una función que recursivamente copia la estructura de la carpeta completa, con subcarpetas, etc... y esto sí lo cumple, es decir, la estructura de carpetas la genera, por tanto me hace dudar que el problema sea de permisos, pero los archivos no los copia nunca.

El código es simple, pero siempre da error:

```
$ftphost = "ftp.destino.com";
$ftpuser = "usuario-ftp";
$ftppass = "pass-ftp";

$conexion = ftp_connect($ftphost);
$ftplogin = ftp_login($conexion, $ftpuser, $ftppass) or die ("Error FTP login");

$origen = "/ftp.php"; //Esto genera la ruta /home/xxxxx/web/dominio/test/ftp.php

//Comprobado que en destino la ruta actual es la que debe ser.
$destino = "/ftp.movido.php";

if(ftp_put($conexion, $destino, $origen, FTP_BINARY))
    echo "OK";
else
    echo "ERROR. <br>origen: $origen<br>destino: $destino";

if(ftp_close($conexion))
    echo "<br><br>OK: Conexión FTP cerrada<br>";
else
    "<br><br>ERROR: No se ha podido cerrar la conexión FTP<br>";
```

Nota: Por probar he intentado también con modo *FTP_ASCII* pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: _Este código siempre da error_ ¿Qué error? Y... ¿por qué no lo haces mediante un script, vía ssh? Iría más rápido y sería más seguro, sobre todo si son archivos pesados. Saludos.

Comment: Pues la cosa es que el fallo da en la linea ftp_put(), pero no consigo acertar a mostrar por pantalla qué error muestra, y hasta donde he visto en php.net, esa función sólo retorna TRUE o FALSE, pero no da un mensaje de error.

La posibilidad de hacerlo mediante script por SSH pues no la he planteado, la dejo cómo último recurso ya que la idea es lograr hacerlo por php.

Comment: Los errores aparecen en el archivo errorlog de la carpeta desde la cual ejecutas tu archivo php. Entiendo que quieras hacerlo por PHP como un reto, pero en este caso la mejor opción es SSH. :)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda A. Cedano, cuando me dijiste "qué error exactamente muestra" y yo te respondí que ninguno porque la función sólo retorna TRUE o FALSE caí en la cuenta que desde php.ini tengo configurado que no muestre warnings ni notices, y al activarlo... magia, el error quedó resuelto en pocos segundos.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. No desactives los errores y los warning :) Dejé dos scripts en una respuesta, por si tuvieras algún problema más adelante pruebes con ellos. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado.

El problema venía porque después de hacer el ftp_login() hay que indicarle a la conexión el modo de transferencia, en este caso PASV. Por tanto el problema se ha resuelto añadiendo

```
ftp_pasv($conexion, true);
```

justo después del ftp_login.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo estos dos scripts que tenía en mi biblioteca de código :).

Uno es para importar, otro para exportar. Como es lógico, el de importar debes usarlo desde el hosting compartido, el de exportar debes ejecutarlo desde el servidor VPS.

Cualquiera de los dos debería funcionar sin problema. Cambia lo que haga falta: nombres de archivo, nombres de usuario, passwords, etc.

### Importar

```
/**
 * Transferir (Importar) Archivos de Servidor a Servidor usando PHP FTP
 */

/* Archivo origen y ruta si necesario */
$remote_file = 'archivo.zip';

/* Cuenta FTP  */
$ftp_host = 'your-ftp-host.com'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'ftp-username@your-ftp-host.com'; /* nombre usuario */
$ftp_user_pass = 'ftppassword'; /* password */


/* Nuevo nombre de archivo para el archivo que se importará */
$local_file = 'archivo.zip';

/* Conectar usando FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

/* Login a FTP */
$login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* Descargar $remote_file y guardar a $local_file */
if ( ftp_get( $connect_it, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
    echo "El archivo $local_file fue transferido con éxito!\n";
}
else {
    echo "Ha habido un error\n";
}

/* Cerrar conexión */
ftp_close( $connect_it );
```

### Exportar

```
/**
 * Transferir (Exportar) Archivos de Servidor a Servidor PHP FTP
 */

/* Nombre de archivo remoto y ruta */
$remote_file = 'files.zip';

/* Cuenta FTP  (Servidor Remoto) */
$ftp_host = 'your-ftp-host.com'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'ftp-username@your-ftp-host.com'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'ftppassword'; /* password */


/* Archivo y Ruta para enviar al Servidor FTP remoto */
$local_file = 'files.zip';

/* Conectar a FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

/* Login a FTP */
$login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* Enviar $local_file a FTP */
if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
    echo "El archivo $local_file fue transferido con éxito!\n";
}
else {
    echo "Hubo un error\n";
}

/* Cerrar conexión */
ftp_close( $connect_it );
```